# Vue.js disable dynamic binding?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am wondering if it is possible to disable the dynamic binding for one instance of an attribute that I am displaying.

Let's just say I have something like this that is working with two way binding:

```
this.$children[0].$data.hits
```

The implementation here is that I have a vacation website where I want to display the total amount of hits which can be derived from this number.

But this number also work with binding so that when you search it gets updated. I want a single instance that does not get updated and shows me the initial count without changing when a user does search.

Is is easily possible or do I just need to set a separate attribute on my components data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So hits is just a number? then assign it to another data prop initially, before users can search. it won't be updated.

```
this.originalHits = this.$children[0].$data.hits
```

Comment: Just a number, I was wondering if there was a Vue.js way of doing this but I guess I will just assign it to another prop yes. Thanks.